# Show/hide drop down if a certain selection is made in previous drop down

Tags: javascript

I have a form. I want to disable or enable a drop down depending on a radio button selection. I need to do this several times in the form. I am new to Javascript so I dont really know where to start. this is a part of the form:

```
<p id="hospitalorientation"><label>Hospital Orientation:</label>
<div id='buttons'>
 <label><input type="radio" name="hospital" /> Not Complete </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="hospital" /> Complete </label>
</div>
<div id="list1" style="display: none;">
 <label>Month Complete: 
<select>
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
```

and then i have basically several replicas of this in the form..

```
<p id="ppd"><label>PPD:</label>
<div id='buttons'>
<label><input type="radio" name="ppd" /> Not Complete </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="ppd" /> Complete </label>
</div>
<div id="list2" style="display: none;">
  <label>Month Complete: 
    <select>
      <option>January</option>
      <option>February</option>
      <option>March</option>
      <option>April</option>
      <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>
```

And now I dont really know where to go from there.

Comment: Why not start with a javascript framework that will allow you to do this with relative ease. jQuery is one of the most popular JS frameworks: http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have value for your radio box and add them ID like "rButtonOne" and "rButtonTwo"

```
<input type="radio" id="rButtonOne" onclick="clicked(this);" value="0">
<input type="radio" id="rButtonTwo" onclick="clicked(this);" value="1">
```

and then javascript

```
function clicked(obj)
{
   if(obj.value == "1")
      document.getElementById('id_of_select_box').disabled = 'disabled';
   else if (obj.value == "0")
      document.getElementById('id_of_select_box').disabled = '';
}
```

this is the approach.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have tried various versions of that javascript but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<p id="hospitalorientation"><label>Hospital Orientation:</label>
<div id='buttons'>
 <label><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="hospital" /> Not Complete </label>
<label><input id="radio2" type="radio" name="hospital" /> Complete </label>
</div>
<div id="list1" style="display: none;">
 <label>Month Complete:
<select>
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("radio1").onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked == true){
        document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "none";
    }
};

document.getElementById("radio2").onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked == true){
        document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aSxXA/

Here is an update, this is a full html page, notice how the body onload event registers the eventHandlers, I think the document may not have been loaded when you were trying to register them before

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            function registerEventHandlers()
            {
            document.getElementById("radio1").onchange = function(){
                hideDiv(this,"list1")
            };
            document.getElementById("radio2").onchange = function(){
                showDiv(this,"list1")
            };
            document.getElementById("radio3").onchange = function(){
                hideDiv(this,"list2")
            };
            document.getElementById("radio4").onchange = function(){
                showDiv(this,"list2")
            };              
            }

            function showDiv(targetElement,toggleElementId){
                    if (targetElement.checked == true) {
                        document.getElementById(toggleElementId).style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById(toggleElementId).style.display = "block";
                    }                
            }
            function hideDiv(targetElement,toggleElementId){
                    if (targetElement.checked == true) {
                        document.getElementById(toggleElementId).style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById(toggleElementId).style.display = "none";
                    }                
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="registerEventHandlers();">
        <p id="hospitalorientation">
            <label>
                Hospital Orientation:
            </label>
            <div id='buttons'>
                <label>
                    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="hospital" /> Not Complete 
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="hospital" /> Complete 
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id="list1" style="display: none;">
                <label>
                    Month Complete: 
                    <select>
                        <option>January</option>
                        <option>February</option>
                        <option>March</option>
                        <option>April</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>June</option>
                        <option>July</option>
                        <option>August</option>
                        <option>September</option>
                        <option>October</option>
                        <option>November</option>
                        <option>December</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <p id="ppd">
                <label>
                    PPD:
                </label>
                <div id='buttons'>
                    <label>
                        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="ppd" /> Not Complete 
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="ppd" /> Complete 
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div id="list2" style="display: none;">
                    <label>
                    Month Complete: 
                    <select>
                        <option>January</option>
                        <option>February</option>
                        <option>March</option>
                        <option>April</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>June</option>
                        <option>July</option>
                        <option>August</option>
                        <option>September</option>
                        <option>October</option>
                        <option>November</option>
                        <option>December</option>
                    </select>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: There has to be something i am doing wrong. i am using notepad++.

Comment: Make sure you added the ids in the html.  Check out the fiddle

Comment: Is your js external or inline?

Comment: inline. I have tried a lot of different things. Most of the DO work in jfiddle but DO NOT when i run it in my program. HELP!!

Comment: @Emily, what about running it in firefox with firebug to debug, see if you get any errors, or do this post a JS fiddle with the html for your page and the js for your page in it then post the link here, if you post this i can take a look at it tomorrow evening or tomorrow morning depending on how hectic work is